# export default vs module.exports differences

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This works:

```
import {bar} from './foo';
bar();

// foo.js
module.exports = {
 bar() {}
}
```

And this works:

```
import foo from './foo';
foo.bar();

// foo.js
export default {
 bar() {}
}
```

So why doesn't this work?

```
import {bar} from './foo';
bar();

// foo.js
export default {
 bar() {}
}
```

It throws `TypeError: (0 , _foo.bar) is not a function`.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

When you have

```
export default {
  bar() {}
}
```

The actual object exported is of the following form:

```
exports: {
  default: {
    bar() {}
  }
}
```

When you do a simple import (e.g., `import foo from './foo';`) you are actually getting the default object inside the import (i.e., `exports.default`). This will become apparent when you run babel to compile to ES5.

When you try to import a specific function (e.g., `import { bar } from './foo';`), as per your case, you are actually trying to get `exports.bar` instead of `exports.default.bar`. Hence why the bar function is undefined.

When you have just multiple exports:

```
export function foo() {};
export function bar() {};
```

You will end up having this object:

```
exports: {
  foo() {},
  bar() {}
}
```

And thus `import { bar } from './foo';` will work. This is the similar case with `module.exports` you are essentially storing an exports object as above. Hence you can import the bar function.

I hope this is clear enough.

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks!

Comment: if I write `module.exports = { funcOne, funcTwo }` how can I best export an object including both of those functions?

Comment: @mesqueeb That's already exported with both of those functions. You should be able to just `import foo from './foo.js';` then execute the function like: `foo.funcOne(); foo.funcTwo();` If you are using `require` then you might have to use `const foo = require('./foo.js').default;`.

Comment: Nice looking, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

curly bracket imports {} are only for named exports.
for default export you are not expected to use them during import.
if you want still use {} for your 3rd case this should work.

```
import {default as bar } from './foo';
bar();

// foo.js
export default {
  bar() {}
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem?

Answer (score -5):

Of course is not working, you exported foo default and imported it with curly braces `{}`. To keep it simple remember this, if you're exporting the default way you need no curly braces, but if you're importing normaly an module, you'll use curly braces `{}` to acces a specific function in the module ;). You can see examples [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export)